# Joining more than 2 tables in order to loop results

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I am able to `join` information from **2 tables** in order to output which users said which status.
It manages to get the users status from `tbl_status` and the username of who said it from `tbl_users`.

But now I would also like to add the **users photo** alongside that status update and output that information in the same query. Not surprisingly the user photos are contained in `tbl_photos`.

How can I add in this additional query into the existing out to output the results with the last query?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT tbl_status.id as statID, tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, tbl_status.date as statDATE, tbl_users.id as usrID, tbl_users.name as usrNAME FROM tbl_status INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is another `JOIN` on the `tbl_photos` table.

I'll have to make some assumptions about `tbl_photos`.

```
SELECT <all your existing columns>, ISNULL(tbl_photos.profile_filename, 'Default Filename') as ProfilePic
FROM tbl_status
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_photos ON tbl_photos.user_id = tbl_users.id
WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0'
```

Comment: @user2527750, does **every user** have a photo? if they don't, you will lose records with this query.

Comment: What do you mean? A photo is optional for users - why would I lose records?

Comment: @user2527750, see my answer, you need a `LEFT JOIN`.  If a user has no photo, that user will be excluded from the query, with the LEFT Join, the user will still remain, and a NULL will be in place of the photo field.

Comment: That's interesting. I was going to set a default image for users before they added their own anyway - thank goodness!

Comment: find a user with no image, run your new query and try finding that user in the result set.  This query will not work for your scenario.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is good to have, as @user2527750 points out.  I updated the code in the answer, wrapping the column with an ISNULL as a way to get the default image (that way, you don't have to set one up for them).

Comment: @MFalanga, you must have it, without it records will be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a left join in case the user has no photo or optional.

```
SELECT  tbl_status.id AS statID ,
            tbl_status.from_user AS statFROM ,
            tbl_status.status AS statSTATUS ,
            tbl_status.deleted AS statDEL ,
            tbl_status.date AS statDATE ,
            tbl_users.id AS usrID ,
            tbl_users.name AS usrNAME,
            p.photo
    FROM    tbl_status
            INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
            Left JOIN tbl_photos p ON tbl_users.id = tbl_photos.userId
    WHERE   tbl_status.deleted = '0'
```

however, if every user has a photo, then use...

```
SELECT  tbl_status.id AS statID ,
        tbl_status.from_user AS statFROM ,
        tbl_status.status AS statSTATUS ,
        tbl_status.deleted AS statDEL ,
        tbl_status.date AS statDATE ,
        tbl_users.id AS usrID ,
        tbl_users.name AS usrNAME,
        p.photo
FROM    tbl_status
        INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
        INNER JOIN tbl_photos p ON tbl_users.id = tbl_photos.userId
WHERE   tbl_status.deleted = '0'
```

You also didn't specify what the FK was, so I just made one up `tbl_users.id = tbl_photos.userId`, you will need to replace this line along with the field you are pulling from the `tbl_photo` table as I used `p.photo`

Answer (score 0):

You would extend the

```
FROM tbl_status INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
```

to

```
FROM tbl_status INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
     INNER JOIN tbl_photo ON tbl_photo.user_id = tbl_users.id
```

The result of a join is treated like a table having all columns of both tables one beside the other in SQL, and hence can be used on either side of another JOIN.